# Reason for job change when current company is closed due to a funding problem

Tags: job-change

My current company is closed due to a funding problem, so I am looking for a new job. But the problem is, what reason should I give for the job change?

Can it create problems for my future?

Side note: in this company we have a notice period of 1 day. Two days ago the manager said that the company is closed due to the problem.

Comment: "what reason i give for job change?" - is there some problem with giving *the truth*?

Comment: may be the company doesn't want to hire person whose comopany is closed(means person's past company is not good).

Comment: can it affect my future?

Comment: "Company closed" is a pretty good explanation, don't you think? Make sure that you collect the references, though. Like, now.

Comment: Does your current company have any objections or confidentiality agreements with you preventing you from letting others know they are going out of business? You don't want to burn bridges with the current company. Those people will be getting jobs as well.

Comment: @Jeffo: How does that sound, "I didn't say we are going OOB. I said that you're running a fire sale on the toilet paper to make the payroll" :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Companies fail. It happens. As long as you aren't the founder or director of finances or someone else who had the power to change that, it should not reflect on the other former employees.

If leading the company was not one of your responsibilities, the success of the company is nothing you have to worry about in your next interviews. The only thing that could reflect badly on you is if you lie about it.

Comment: Thanaks @nvoigt, it is useful

Comment: Seconded.  I've been in this position, and anything in the space of "the company went out of business" or (since this one hasn't *yet*) "I'm concerned about my current employer's viability" hasn't raised eyebrows for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply tell them the truth. I think they'll understand your situation.
Secondly if they ask for reason for closing of company then you can tell them about their irresponsible nature which could be the reason for company being shut down (As you said you only got one day notice).

And you did'nt play any role which could be the cause of company being closed so no future problem.